# AWK PRINTF Not printing numbers correctly

Tags: command-line, printing, awk

I have this file:

file1:

```
ATOM      1  N   LEU     1     -10.186 -21.276  -0.497  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      2  HT1 LEU     1     -10.773 -22.005  -0.843  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      3  HT2 LEU     1      -9.316 -21.441  -0.958  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      4  HT3 LEU     1     -10.007 -21.389   0.478  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      5  CA  LEU     1     -10.642 -19.924  -0.729  1.00  0.00      PROT
ATOM      6  HA  LEU     1     -10.092 -19.286  -0.214  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      7  CB  LEU     1     -10.604 -19.551  -2.214  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      8  HB1 LEU     1     -11.432 -19.802  -2.731  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM      9  HB2 LEU     1      -9.764 -19.989  -2.566  1.00  1.00      PROT
ATOM     10  CG  LEU     1     -10.447 -17.969  -2.340  1.00  1.00      PROT
```

When I do:

```
cat file1 | awk '{printf "%4s%7.0f%5s%5s%5s%12.3f%8.3f%8.3f%6.2f%6.2f%10s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11}'
```

I get:

```
ATOM      1    N  LEU    1     -10,000 -21,000  -0,000  1,00  0,00      PROT
ATOM      2  HT1  LEU    1     -10,000 -22,000  -0,000  1,00  0,00      PROT
ATOM      3  HT2  LEU    1      -9,000 -21,000  -0,000  1,00  0,00      PROT
ATOM      4  HT3  LEU    1     -10,000 -21,000   0,000  1,00  0,00      PROT
ATOM      5   CA  LEU    1     -10,000 -19,000  -0,000  1,00  0,00      PROT
ATOM      6   HA  LEU    1     -10,000 -19,000  -0,000  1,00  1,00      PROT
ATOM      7   CB  LEU    1     -10,000 -19,000  -2,000  1,00  1,00      PROT
ATOM      8  HB1  LEU    1     -11,000 -19,000  -2,000  1,00  1,00      PROT
ATOM      9  HB2  LEU    1      -9,000 -19,000  -2,000  1,00  1,00      PROT
ATOM     10   CG  LEU    1     -10,000 -17,000  -2,000  1,00  1,00      PROT
```

Columns 6-8 are not the same between input and output.

Comment: What implementation/version of awk are you using? What is your locale (in particular, the value of `LC_NUMERIC`)? At least in the case of GNU awk (aka `gawk`) this may be a result of how POSIX and your locale interact. See for example  [Locales Can Influence Conversion](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Locale-influences-conversions)

Comment: the locale is Colombia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if

1. your locale is one in which `,` is the decimal separator; **and**
2. awk is implementing the POSIX standard for numeric conversion

Ex. with GNU awk (aka `gawk`)

```
$ printf '1.23' | POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 LC_NUMERIC=es_CO.utf-8 gawk '{printf("%.3f\n", $1)}'
1,000
```

whereas both

```
$ printf '1.23' | LC_NUMERIC=es_CO.utf-8 gawk '{printf("%.3f\n", $1)}'
1.230
$ printf '1.23' | POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 gawk '{printf("%.3f\n", $1)}'
1.230
```

preserve the decimal.

See [The GNU Awk Users' Guide: 6.1.4.2 Locales Can Influence Conversion](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Locale-influences-conversions)